# Simulating touch on screen break real input finger

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing critical problem for this concept which is that when simulating touch event on screen ( tested motionEvent, dispatch gesture, input tap x y and even low level shell click - sendevent) real finger touch event is canceled.

In this code I war trying to separate physical touch event from simulating one but it is still doesn't work.

```
package com.example.myapplication2

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.graphics.Path
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
import android.widget.Button
import java.util.LinkedList


class TouchEventProcessor {
    private val physicalTouchEvents = LinkedList<MotionEvent>()
    private val simulatedTouchEvents = LinkedList<MotionEvent>()

    fun addPhysicalTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) {
        physicalTouchEvents.add(event)
    }

    fun addSimulatedTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) {
        simulatedTouchEvents.add(event)
    }

    fun processEvents() {
        // Przetwarzanie zdarzeń fizycznych
        while (physicalTouchEvents.isNotEmpty()) {
            val event = physicalTouchEvents.poll()
            // Tutaj dodajemy logikę przetwarzania zdarzenia fizycznego
            Log.d("TouchEventProcessor", "Przetwarzanie fizycznego zdarzenia dotykowego: $event")
        }

        // Przetwarzanie zdarzeń symulowanych
        while (simulatedTouchEvents.isNotEmpty()) {
            val event = simulatedTouchEvents.poll()
            // Tutaj dodajemy logikę przetwarzania zdarzenia symulowanego
            Log.d("TouchEventProcessor", "Przetwarzanie symulowanego zdarzenia dotykowego: $event")
        }
    }
}


class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager
    private var overlayView: View? = null
    private val touchEventProcessor = TouchEventProcessor()


    private val motionEventReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == MainActivity.ACTION_MOTION_EVENT) {
                val x = intent.getFloatExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MOTION_EVENT_X, 0f)
                val y = intent.getFloatExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MOTION_EVENT_Y, 0f)
                val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                val motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    currentTime,
                    currentTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    x,
                    y,
                    0
                )
                touchEventProcessor.addPhysicalTouchEvent(motionEvent)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        val filter = IntentFilter(MainActivity.ACTION_MOTION_EVENT)
        registerReceiver(motionEventReceiver, filter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)

        // Utwórz i skonfiguruj widok nakładki
        val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null)

        // Konfiguracja parametrów WindowManager
        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )

        // Ustaw pozycję i inne parametry (opcjonalnie)
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
        params.x = 0
        params.y = 0

        // Dodaj widok do WindowManager
        windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        windowManager.addView(overlayView, params)

        // Konfiguracja przycisku na nakładce (jeśli jest potrzebny)
        val tl1 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tl1)
        tl1?.setOnClickListener {
            //simulateTouch(1809f, 107f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
        val tl2 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tl2)
        tl2?.setOnClickListener {
            simulateTouch(2000f, 603f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
        val tl3 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tl3)
        tl3?.setOnClickListener {
            //simulateTouch(1809f, 107f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
        val tr1 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tr1)
        tr1?.setOnClickListener {
            //simulateTouch(1809f, 107f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
        val tr2 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tr2)
        tr2?.setOnClickListener {
            simulateTouch(230f, 588f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
        val tr3 = overlayView?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.tr3)
        tr3?.setOnClickListener {
           // simulateTouch(1809f, 107f)// Logika po kliknięciu przycisku
        }
    }

    private fun simulateTouch(x: Float, y: Float) {
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(x, y)
        }
        val gestureBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        val strokeBuilder = GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 100)
        gestureBuilder.addStroke(strokeBuilder)
        val gesture = gestureBuilder.build()

        dispatchGesture(gesture, null, null)

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        touchEventProcessor.addSimulatedTouchEvent(
            MotionEvent.obtain(
                currentTime, // downTime
                currentTime, // eventTime
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, // action
                x, // x coordinate
                y, // y coordinate
                0  // metaState
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        touchEventProcessor.processEvents()

    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interrupt
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(motionEventReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
        if (overlayView != null) {
            windowManager.removeView(overlayView)
            overlayView = null
        }
    }
}
```